# p4v won't start: Unable to login as user "

Tags: perforce

I am running p4v on Ubuntu. Usually I login to p4 at a terminal window and then start p4v. However, this morning I started p4v before logging in at the terminal. I got the connection dialog which I quickly exited, went to the terminal and did p4 login, and then tried to start p4v again.

Now when I double-click the p4v icon on my desktop, all I get is the message:

> Unable to login to SERVERNAME as user "

(that lone double quote at the end is not a typo -- it's exactly what the message says).

and p4v won't start. The message box says "Try again?", and whether I click Yes or No, it won't start. How do I get past this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit ~/.p4qt/ApplicationSettings.xml and change the value for  `ConnectionStartOption` to 3, as shown below:

```
<Int varName="ConnectionStartOption">3</Int>
```

Comment: This is the right answer for more recent versions of p4v. For example, I just confirmed that it worked on 2018.3/1719707

Comment: Can confirm this is still the right thing, as of p4v version 2022.2/2336701

Further, C:\Users\YourName\.p4qt\ is likely the directory to look in to find ApplicationSettings.xml.

Answer (score 2):

For older versions of p4, edit ~/.p4qt/ApplicationSettings.xml

In the line

```
<String varName="StartupOption">Last</String>
```

change `Last` --> `Dialog`

Next time you start, you should get the Connections dialogue. You can either use a previous working connection, or fill in the fields with the correct settings.